# How to change background color before calling a function or doing something else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the color of the "lol" button before calling `testFunction()`.

```js
function testFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  return 0;
}

$("button").click(function() {
  $("button").css("background-color", "#6ddc5d");
  testFunction();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>lol</button>
```

And How Can I do the same, without a function? Example code below:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("button").css("background-color", "#6ddc5d");
  
  // change color, then run this below operation
  
   for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) 
    console.log(i);
    
    // more stuff here

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>lol</button>
```

Comment: You are.  What's the question?

Comment: Just in case this is a question based on timing.  Javascript will not wait for the background color to be redrawn before continuing on with the processing.  So it is highly likely that it will go through your loop before the browser is given a chance to redraw/reflow

Comment: You're already doing it

Comment: This works on my FF on mac but it might not on other browsers, you can put the function call in a timeout of 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because the loop you're running is synchronous. This blocks the UI thread from updating the background colour you amend.

To solve this, call the `testFunction()` within a timeout with `0` delay:

```js
function testFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  return 0;
}

$("button").click(function() {
  $("button").css("background-color", "#6ddc5d");
  setTimeout(testFunction, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>lol</button>
```

The logic for your version without the function is the same, you just need to wrap it in a `setInterval()`:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("button").css("background-color", "#6ddc5d");

  setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>lol</button>
```

Comment: Hey, I edited my question, can you also tell me, How to solve the second part of the question?

Comment: The logic is the same without the function, just wrap the `for` loop in the `setInterval()`. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Ohh, you did what I asked for. But I only provided an example code. My original code is very big, and I cannot provide it here. 

In my code, your solution works around 70% of the time only. Sometimes, it doesn't.  Do you have any idea why? Does the browser ignore your solution sometimes for some reasons? or unable to load it something?

Comment: In that case try making the delay longer. Try `25` instead of `0`. In basic terms you need to set the delay so that it gives the UI enough time to update *before* you start the loop. On a slower computer the longer you will need to delay.

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot for such a great information :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a worker if you didn't want to use a timeout. This will allow you to run heavy long running loads that take longer than the timeout.

**Note 1:** This works in all browsers, but seems to work the best in FireFox.
**Note 2:** Edge complains about the inline script when using `createObjectURL`, so an external script would be better.

```js
// Get the worker form an inline script
var blob = new Blob([document.querySelector('#worker1').textContent ], { type: "text/javascript" })
// Get the URL to the worker (can use an external file)
var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))

// Listen for messages from the worker
// When when get one handle it
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log(e.data)
}

// Once clicked change the color, then send a message to the worker
$("button").click(function() {
  $("button").css("background-color", "#6ddc5d")
  worker.postMessage('')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>lol</button>

<!-- Place the contents of the below script in an external js file if desired -->
<script id="worker1" type="javascript/worker">
// Listen for messages from the main process
self.onmessage = function(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    // Send messages back to the main process
    self.postMessage(i)
  }
  return 0;
}
</script>
```

The above example uses an inline worker, you could replace it with an external `.js` file if you wanted, you would just need to remove the `var blob = ...` line and replace `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` with the URL to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want it to be executed seperately. In this case you need to make it async with let's say setTimeout.

```js
function testFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  return 0;
}

$("button").click(function() {
  $("button").css("background-color", "#6ddc5d");
  setTimeout(function() { testFunction(); },0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>lol</button>
```

Comment: Hey, I edited my question, can you also tell me, How to solve the second part of the question?